# namedQueries error grails

Tags: grails, dynamic-queries

I have a domain class `DefectData` as follows

```
class DefectData {
String taskId
String defectId
String defectSummary
String severity
String phaseDetected
String rejected
String loggedBy
String howFound
Date dateFound 
String defectType
String defectCause
ProgressData progressData
def DefectData(){}

static constraints = {
    id generator:"assigned",name:"defectId"

}
static belongsTo=[taskId:ProgressData]
static namedQueries={
    getDefectDataByYearMonth{int month,int year ->
    def plannedDate=Date.parse("mm-yy","${month} - ${year}")
    }
}
}
```

I am trying this sort of query, which would enable me to get the count of the defects of which were detected in the "Testing" phase.

```
 def testingDefects(int month,int year){
          countTestingDefects=DefectData.getDefectDataByYearMonth(month,year).findAllWhere(phaseDetected:"Testing").count()
    println countTestingDefects
}
```

Though, I am getting this error, that the date is unparseable

```
testingDefects(03,2012)
```

Unparsable date "3-12". I just want to list the records on the basis of the month and the year.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just throw away your spaces

```
def (month,year) = [2,2012]
Date.parse("mm-yy","${month}-${year}")
```

works for me

Give a try to  [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you need more control and ease about date parsing